# Replace the value of a bool in object within an object with the value of an array

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to figure out how to do this for a few hours and idk why I am so lost.

I'm trying to replace the value of an of toppings for each pie in the pies object with the *pretty names* from the toppings array.

I'm struggling to explain this without an example (please see below).

i.e. {whippedCream: true} => {"Whipped cream"}

```
const toppings = ["Whipped cream", "Powdered sugar"]

const pies = [
{
        name: "Cherry Pie",
        toppings: 
        {
                whippedCream: true, 
                powderedSugar: true
        }
},{
        name: "Blueberry Pie",
        toppings: 
        {
                whippedCream: true,
        }
}]
```

I would really appreciate any help you can provide with doing this.

**Edit:** toppings = [{name: "Whipped cream"}, {name: "Powdered sugar"}]

Comment: `{"Whipped cream"}` is not valid syntax - objects require key-value pairs, not just values

Comment: Okay so say we make toppings = [{name: "Whipped cream"}, {name: "Powdered sugar"}], then how would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want an lookup object to translate your camel-case toppings into the pretty format:

```
const toppingsLookup = {
  whippedCream: "Whipped cream",
  powderedSugar: "Powdered sugar"
}
```

Now you can actually perform the lookup. You can do this with the array you provided like so:

```js
const toppingsLookup = {
  whippedCream: "Whipped cream",
  powderedSugar: "Powdered sugar"
};

const pies = [{
    name: "Cherry Pie",
    toppings: { whippedCream: true, powderedSugar: true }
  }, {
    name: "Blueberry Pie",
    toppings: { whippedCream: true }
}];

const formatted = pies.map(pie => {
  const toppings = Object.entries(pie.toppings).reduce((acc, [topping, hasTopping]) => {
    if (hasTopping) {
      acc.push(toppingsLookup[topping]);
    }
    return acc;
  }, [])
  
  return {...pie, toppings};
})

console.log(formatted);
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Now that the question was edited for clarification, this code will convert the original pies object into the format where each pie's toppings property is an array of objects with name properties:

```
pies.forEach((pie) => {
    const toppingsBool = pie.toppings;
    pie.toppings = [];

    if (toppingsBool.whippedCream) {
      pie.toppings.push({name: toppings[0]});
    }
    if (toppingsBool.powderedSugar) {
      pie.toppings.push({name: toppings[1]});
    }
})
```